# How to convert a Result into an Option inside iterator chain?

Tags: rust, iteration, filter-map

I've written this:

```
    /* Turn a Vec<Vec<u8>> into a Vec<String>, without re-allocating the inner bytes. */
    let lines: Vec<String> = u8_lines.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|u8_line| match String::from_utf8(u8_line) {
                Ok(u8_line) => Some(u8_line),
                Err(_) => None,
        })
        .collect();
```

Is there a way of simplifying this by replacing the `match` or the `filter_map`?

Comment: For future reference, you can search queries like `fn: Result -> Option` on [docs.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/?search=fn%3A%20Result%20-%3E%20Option) to search for specific signatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to turn a `Result<T, E>` into an `Option<T>`:

```rust
    /* Turn a Vec<Vec<u8>> into a Vec<String>, without re-allocating the inner bytes. */
    let lines: Vec<String> = u8_lines.into_iter()
        .filter_map(|u8_line| String::from_utf8(u8_line).ok())
        .collect();
```